# Creating user in tableau server using rest api and c#

Tags: c#, tableau-api

I am working on an asp.net web application where I have to create users directly in Tableau Server using Rest API and C#. The users are local users and not AD or SAML users.

I have coded the part however,  I am getting Unauthorised as the result. Below is my code.

```
        public static string site_id { get; set; }
        public static string token { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallWebAPIAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://serverurl.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                SignIn(client);
                Users(client, site_id, token);
                CreateUser(client, site_id, token);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        public class CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
        {
            public CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter()
            {
                UseXmlSerializer = true;
                WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
            }
        }
        public static tableauCredentialsType SignIn(HttpClient client)
        {
            var name = "Administrator";
            var password = "Password";
            var site = string.Empty;

            var tableauCredentialsType = new tsRequest()
            {
                Item = new tableauCredentialsType
                {
                    name = name,
                    password = password,
                    site = new siteType() { contentUrl = site }
                }
            };

            var httpContent = new ObjectContent<tsRequest>(tableauCredentialsType, new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter());

            var httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync("/api/3.2/auth/signin", httpContent).Result;

            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to login to the server", site, name));

            var responseLogin = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<tsResponse>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() { new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;

            var resultTableauCredentialsType = ((tableauCredentialsType)responseLogin.Items[0]);

            site_id = resultTableauCredentialsType.site.id;

            token = resultTableauCredentialsType.token;

            return resultTableauCredentialsType;

        }

        public static userType CreateUser(HttpClient client, string siteid, string auth_token)
        {
            var name = "user@domain.com";

            var userType = new tsRequest()
            {
                Item = new userType
                {
                    name = name,
                    siteRole = siteRoleType.ExplorerCanPublish,
                    authSetting = siteUserAuthSettingType.ServerDefault             
                }
            };

            var httpContent = new ObjectContent<tsRequest>(userType, new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter());

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-tableau-auth", auth_token);

            var uri = string.Format("/api/3.2/sites/{0}/users", siteid);

            var httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, httpContent).Result;

            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to create user in the server", siteid, name));

            var responseLogin = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<tsResponse>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() { new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;

            var resultTableauCredentialsType = ((userType)responseLogin.Items[0]);

            return resultTableauCredentialsType;
        }
```

I was able to successfully login into the server and was also able to provide the x-tableau-auth to my client headers.

The code is working fine except the post sync method in Create user method. Once the code executes, it throws UnAuthorized error as the response from the server. My user is the administrator in Tableau Server and when I query the workbooks and users in Tableau Server with the same x-tableau-auth, it's working fine.

I am not good in API programming and need some help in solving out this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.